# PHP: Finding ALL of the products of 3 in an array using a for loop

Tags: php, arrays, key

I want to find all of the numbers evenly divisible by 3 in an array. Here is my code so far:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 14, 18, 20, 21);

for ($i = min($array); $i <= max($array); $i++)
{  
    if ($i % 3 == 0)
    {
        echo $i;
    echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

Of course, I realize that `$i++` is not right. Doing it this way simply takes the lowest value in my array (1) and adds one to it until it reaches the highest value in my array (21). Doing this results in numbers such as 9 and 15 that are not in my array.

I know what I really need to do is start at a key value of 0 and end at a key value of 9 (or 10?). I was thing of something along the lines of

```
$i = min(array_keys($array) + 1
```

but this does not work.

I guess what I am asking is how do I increment by key? Am I on the right track to solving this? I understand I can use a `foreach` loop, but this will only give me the very last product. Maybe a `while` loop would work?

Comment: Why increment at all?  Just loop through your array.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following :

```
foreach ($array as $value){  
   if ($value % 3 == 0){
      echo $value;
      echo "<br />";
   }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. For whatever reason when I wrote my foreach loop it would only return the very last value and not all of them. I will have to compare my previous code to yours. Thanks!

Comment: @amofo : Glad to help you!Mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

What about use `count( $array )` to get array's length and iterate?

```
for($i = 0; $i < count( $array ); $i++){
    if( $array[ $i ] % 3 == 0){
        /* do something */
    }
}
```